# static __forceinline or __forceinline static

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Good morning, this always made me wonder (even tho it doesn't really matter) but which one is the correct way? Or is there none and both ways are fine?

```
static __forceinline T some_func ( )
```

or

```
__forceinline static  T some_func ( )
```

Comment: AFAIK `__forceinline` is *not* in [standard C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) so your question is implementation (and compiler) specific. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) your code don't even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, both are legal and their results are identical so it comes down on personal preference.

For what it's worth in most codebases I've worked compiler specific keywords were always used before any standard C++ keywords which makes your 2nd snippet more common.

However as always with code style, just pick one you like most and be consistent. Consistency is what's important.

Comment: I've always used static __forceinline so i guess i will stay with that.

Comment: `__forceinline` is *not* in [standard C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) so neither are *legal* in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) and my [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) 7 rightly rejects both. Perhaps there is some particular C++ implementation accepting that as an *extension*. Then read its documentation (or trust that implementation, so test both)

Comment: BasileStarynkevitch Of course I was referring to MSVC only, which this question is based on. I only said that code was legal for MSVC, not that it was standard C++.

Comment: This problem is the #1 of my list of the ten most important problems in computer sciences. We should solve it immediately to continue on #2 - #10.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to order modifiers alphabetically, except if you are writing code on the solstice or equinox (during which it angers the sun microsystems god).

Other than that, use whatever order you wish, so long as you are willing to live with the consequences.

Which are none.